# How to use OpenMP in a C project built with meson

Tags: c, meson-build

I am quite new to meson and C, please forgive me if the answer to this question is trivial ...

I want to use OpenMP in a C project, and I am using meson as a build tool.
I want to compile the `parallel for` example from this [tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SECTIONS).
My `main.c` looks very similar:

```
#include <omp.h>
#define N       1000
#define CHUNKSIZE   100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i, chunk;
  float a[N], b[N], c[N];

  /* Some initializations */
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = b[i] = i * 1.0;
  chunk = CHUNKSIZE;

#pragma omp parallel for      \
  shared(a,b,c,chunk) private(i)  \
  schedule(static,chunk)
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];

  return 0;
}
```

My short `meson.build` file contains this:

```
project('openmp_with_meson', 'c')

# add_project_arguments('-fopenmp', language: 'c')

exe = executable('some_exe', 'src/main.c') #, c_args: '-fopenmp')
```

I commented out the `c_args` keyword in the call to `executable` here.
Now I end up with the following scenarios:

- without `'-fopenmp'` option, I get the warning, that the `pragma` is unknown and will be ignored (as I would expect): `../src/main.c:15:0: warning: ignoring pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas] #pragma omp parallel for`
- with the option `c_args: '-fopenmp'` inserted, I do not get the above warning anymore, instead I get errors for undefined references to `GOMP_parallel`, `omp_get_num_threads` and `omp_get_thread_num`, and nothing gets built
- when I use gcc manually with `gcc -Wall -o manually_with_gcc ../src/main.c -fopenmp` the program compiles and executes without any errors.

Can anyone tell me how to get the executable to compile with meson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Meson 0.46 or later**

Meson 0.46 ([released](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/releases/tag/0.46.0) Apr 23, 2018) [added OpenMP support](https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-46-0.html#addition-of-openmp-dependency). So, if you have meson 0.46 or later,

```
project('openmp_with_meson', 'c')
omp = dependency('openmp')
exe = executable('some_exe', 'src/main.c',
                 dependencies : omp)
```

Should work with both GCC and Clang.

**Meson 0.45 or earlier**

If you happen to have older version, Debian Stretch, Ubuntu Bionic (18.04LTS), or Fedora 27, you can do the following:

You need another keyword arg `link_args : '-fopenmp'` for `executable()`.

```
exe = executable('some_exe', 'src/main.c',
                 c_args: '-fopenmp',
                 link_args : '-fopenmp')
```

Meson builds C program in two phases, compiling and linking.  You can pass extra arguments with `c_args` for compiling and `link_args` for linking.

The option `-fopenmp` enables OpenMP directives while compiling, and

> [the flag also arranges for automatic linking of the OpenMP runtime
> library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html).

That is, `-fopenmp` is dual purpose option.

Now, the above is simple and good.  Once you understand it, however, you can also compile your program with `-fopenmp` to activate the OpenMP directives and link the OpenMP libraries by yourself **without** `-fopenmp` to the `link_args`.

Here is a complete `meson.build`:

```
project('openmp_with_meson', 'c')
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
libgomp = cc.find_library('gomp')
exe = executable('some_exe', 'src/main.c',
                 c_args: '-fopenmp',
                 dependencies : libgomp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Meson >= `0.46` now has a builtin for this ([docs](https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-46-0.html#addition-of-openmp-dependency)):

```py
openmp = dependency('openmp') # meson builtin
```